# Accessing a select HTML Element from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `JavaScript object` that returns `HTML information` to populate a responsive web application.  I am having an issue accessing a select box with a class to identify it and grab the selected option it contains.

**Here is what I am doing:**

```
var EditRowRestriction = OptionRules.prototype.getEditRowRestriction(j); <!-- THIS IS THE OBJECT THAT CALLS A METHOD TO POPULATE HTML ELEMENTS TO BE SENT BACK TO THAN BE USED TO POPULATE SCREEN
var check = $(EditRowRestriction).find("select");

console.log(check);
```

Here is an example of what `check` would respond with:

```
select.restirction-select <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT
context: tr
length: 1
prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1]
selector: "select"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Now that I am able to log that, if I try doing something like, `check[0].find(':selected').text();`

It would respond with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Now if I just output the `check[0]` I get this: `<select></select>`.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here is an example of how `select` is being populated

```
var sel = document.createElement("select");

    $.ajax({
        url: "actions/....php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            'function' : "admin_populate_global",
            'elevation_name' : '',
            'user' : $("li.selected").text()
        },
        success: function(data){

            // FIRST MAKE SURE DATA WAS FOUND
            if(data["status"] == "found")
            {
                    var restrictionArray = data["data_retrieved"].split(',');
                        var events = $(".option-rule-item").map(function() {
                            if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
                            {
                            }
                            else
                                return this.innerHTML;
                        }).get();

                        var checkReturnedText = $.trim(restrictionArray[loop_amount]);

                        sel.className ="restirction-select";

                        var opt = document.createElement("option");

                        opt.innerHTML = checkReturnedText;
                        opt.setAttribute("value", checkReturnedText);
                        sel.appendChild(opt);
                        for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(checkReturnedText == events[i])
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                                var event = events[i];
                                opt.innerHTML = event;
                                opt.setAttribute("value", event);
                                sel.appendChild(opt);
                            }
                        }


            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("An error occured, please try again.");
        }
    });
    return sel;
```

Comment: `check[0]` is a DOM object so you can't use jQuery methods on it, what do you get using `check.find(...`?

Comment: @charlietfl `check.find(':selected').text()` outputs nothing.

Comment: is anything selected ?  try logging  `check.html()`

Comment: @charlietfl ya nothing outputs

Comment: The select boxes are being created through AJAX calls within those methods to populate the forms so that could be why?

Comment: so it has no children, so nothing can be selected then

Comment: @charlietfl but something is being selected and these are populated select boxes, check update for sample of how they are populated

Comment: Why put non instance specific methods on the prototype?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am using a Standard Object type and whats happening is that data that the method being called in the above returns and the prototype is used to communicated and populate.

Comment: you can't return `sel` from outside the success handler... will just be empty `select`

Comment: @charlietfl but than why is my data populating correctly?

Comment: but if you are checking the children as soon as you return it, the ajax hasn't completed because it is asynchronous

Comment: I thought of that to!  I can try to put a wait?

Comment: either do what you need to in the ajax callback or look into using a promise